# Having trouble understanding the logic behind "If..Then Go To" in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I am reading through some VBA code written by someone else and I can't understand the logic behind it:

```
Sheets("IC View").Select
RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If RowCount <= 9 Then GoTo skipNoChange

    'Sheets("IC View").Select
    Range("A1:BG1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range(Cells(10, "A"), Cells(LastRowIC, 
   "BG")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    Worksheets("IC Log").Select
    nextRowLog = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & nextRowLog).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

skipNoChange:

Sheets("IC View").Select
zeroCheck = 2   'start at column 3
    Do While Cells(9, zeroCheck + 1).value <> "Checked_By"
        If Cells(9, zeroCheck + 1).value = "" Then Columns(zeroCheck + 
        1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        If Cells(9, zeroCheck + 1).value <> "" Then Columns(zeroCheck + 
        1).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        zeroCheck = zeroCheck + 1
     Loop

'==================================
Call checkFreesaleChanges
```

So if the row count is less than or equal to 9 then i understand it needs to go 'SkipNoChange', but where does 'SkipNoChange end? Does it end at 'zeroCheck ... Loop' and then moves on to 'Call checkFreesaleChanges'?

What happens if the row count is greater than 9? Does it continue with the code but doesn't run the bit between 'skipNoChange: ...Loop' but does run CallcheckFreesaleChanges onwards?

Comment: *but where does 'SkipNoChange end?* it doesn't. I recommend you use if then... end if instead it makes the code easier to read in my opinion

Comment: @Andreas I am just trying to understand what is happening in the code as I can't change it without knowing the logic. Surely 'skipNoChange' ends somewhere because if the row count is greater than 9, then there needs to be some lines (related to skipNoChange) that aren't run?

Comment: No. You say to the compiler if rowcount is more than 9 *"skip all this and just resume as normal from there."*. There is no end to it. It's like telling someone to walk *that* direction.

Comment: @andreas skip all of what though? and resume from where? .. just reading through your answer now though :)

Comment: Skip from when you say GoTo, until the you find the word that matches. In your case you want to skip from the if rowcount line to the line where it says `skipNoChange:` and then the code resumes from there.

Comment: The current logic is just: if rowcount <= 9 then skip all the lines between here and the skipNoChange label, otherwise just run everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a if then.... Else.... end if.

It makes the code easier to read and easier to follow in my opinion.
Adding comments to the else and end if rows means you don't need to scroll up and down to see what the else or end if is for.

```
Sheets("IC View").Select
RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


If RowCount > 9 Then 
    'Sheets("IC View").Select
    Range("A1:BG1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range(Cells(10, "A"), Cells(LastRowIC, 
   "BG")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    Worksheets("IC Log").Select
    nextRowLog = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & nextRowLog).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Else ' rowcount is less than 9
    msgbox "Rowcount is less than 9"
End If ' end of if rowcount syntax

Sheets("IC View").Select
zeroCheck = 2   'start at column 3
    Do While Cells(9, zeroCheck + 1).value <> "Checked_By"
        If Cells(9, zeroCheck + 1).value = "" Then Columns(zeroCheck + 
        1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        If Cells(9, zeroCheck + 1).value <> "" Then Columns(zeroCheck + 
        1).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        zeroCheck = zeroCheck + 1
     Loop

'==================================
Call checkFreesaleChanges
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sorath no problem. Also another trip is to use the debugger in VBA editor. Press F8 and the code will run one line at the time. If you the use the immediate window, then you can write `Rowcount = 5` and step down to your if and see what happens. Then just drag the yellow line up and input `Rowcount = 15` in the immediate window and try again with F8

Comment: Sorry, i thought I got my head around the logic but I'm confused again! is 'Then' and 'GoTo' meant to be read together? because by your logic GoTo skipNoChange happens when rowcount >9 @andreas

Comment: I think you were meant to write "Run code in red if rowcount >9"

Answer (score 2):

`skipNoChange:`  is a label, a place holder. You can use any word ending thit a colon `:`

It's often used for error handling in VBA.

```
Sub DoSomething
   on error goto hell
   'some code here
   ....
Ciao:
   exit Sub

hell:
   msgbox "Shit happens"
   resume Ciao

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[GoTo Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/goto-statement)

> Branches unconditionally to a specified line within a procedure.
>
> Syntax GoTo line
>
> The required line argument can be any line label or line number.

`skipNoChange:`  is a line label as indicated by the fact it is completely to the left and the line ends with `:` and nothing after.  Try and indent the label - it will move back to the left hand side of the code pane.

In your example:

```
If RowCount <= 9 Then GoTo skipNoChange
```

where `RowCount` is determined by `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`, you are saying if the last populated row in column A of the activesheet, determined by coming up from the bottom of the sheet, is <=9 then branch the code to the line label `skipNoChange`.  This is a conditional transfer of control. The program control shifts to the line label. The lines between this conditional test and the label are not executed as this point. If code later loops back and the condition is not met then they may in future be executed. The program continues to execute from the label onwards. It pretty much is as on tin "GoTo".

To many `GoTo`s make program flow hard to follow and read. Usually you can re-write to use a different control flow structure as shown in at least one of the other answers.

It's something of a relic from before structured programming really took off. Interesting reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto).